# why we need action="*" attribute on operation contract when using netmessagebinding element

Tags: wcf, azureservicebus

We are publish message i.e brokered message object with body content type "string" to window server service bus on topics and pulling the message from topic/subscription using WCF service. all the example we have seen on the internet uses Action attribute with "*" on operationcontract/servicemethod , why do we need to mark as  action "*" while using netmessagebinding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a service contract with multiple operations, the SOAP action header value is used to identify which operation is being invoked through the input message. In the NetMessageBinding case, the input message is not a SOAP message itself, so there will be no SOAP action value that can be used to dispatch the operation.

To work around that, WCF allows you to define "catch-all" operations, by marking them with Action="*", which means that any message that was not explicitly routed to some operation through the normal mechanics will be dispatched to the catch-all operation.

So, in essence, what you're doing here is telling WCF to process all incoming messages through this operation in the service contract.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way that I can have two operation contract within the same service contract, listing to two different topics/subscription. any work around?

Comment: You could possibly define multiple service contracts and expose each one from a separate endpoint tied to a specific queue/subscription on the same service. Though, honestly, I fail to see how this would be very desirable.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need to process multiple topics/subscriptions on the same service?

Comment: yes I was wrong to have many topic/subscriptions on the same service. As per your suggestion defining multiple service contracts and expose each one from a separate endpoint tied to a specific queue/subscription on the same service will work.. Thanks tomsar